# DataGridView initial load is superfast, sequential refreshes are VERY SLOW (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, performance, datagridview

So I have a DataGridView view form that loads superfast initially, but when I refresh it takes forever to populate it. You can literally see every line being drawn. Grid has about 1000 lines.

When the form loads, it calls refreshPendingsGrid(). When the user double-clicks on any record in the DataGridView it calls the same refreshPendingsGrid() function again. What would cause the DataGridView to refresh 10 times slower compared to initial load?

Thank you.

```
Private Sub frmReviewPendings_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    refreshPendingsGrid()
End Sub


Private Function refreshPendingsGrid()
    DoubleBuffer.DoubleBuffered(dgvPendings, True)
    dgvPendings.Rows.Clear()
    dgvPendings.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    dgvPendings.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
    dgvPendings.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
    dgvPendings.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing

        If RS.EOF And RS.BOF Then
            'there are no rows to add
            If Not (RS Is Nothing) Then RS.Close()
            RS = Nothing
            If Not (DB Is Nothing) Then DB.Close()
            DB = Nothing

            Return 1
        Else
            'loop through all the rows and add them to the table
            RS.MoveFirst()

            dgvPendings.RowCount = RS.RecordCount

            y = 0
            Do Until RS.EOF

                Application.DoEvents()

                dgvPendings.Rows.Item(y).Cells("xxxxxxxx").Value = IIf(IsDBNull(RS.Fields("xxxxxxxx").Value), "", RS.Fields("xxxxxxxx").Value)
                dgvPendings.Rows.Item(y).Cells("xxxxxxxx").Value = IIf(IsDBNull(RS.Fields("xxxxxxxx").Value), "", RS.Fields("xxxxxxxx").Value)
                dgvPendings.Rows.Item(y).Cells("xxxxxxxx").Value = IIf(IsDBNull(RS.Fields("xxxxxxxx").Value), "", RS.Fields("xxxxxxxx").Value)
                dgvPendings.Rows.Item(y).Cells("xxxxxxxx").Value = IIf(IsDBNull(RS.Fields("xxxxxxxx").Value), "", RS.Fields("xxxxxxxx").Value)
                dgvPendings.Rows.Item(y).Cells("xxxxxxxx").Value = IIf(IsDBNull(RS.Fields("xxxxxxxx").Value), "", RS.Fields("xxxxxxxx").Value)

                RS.MoveNext()

                If Not dgvPendings.RowCount = RS.RecordCount Then
                    dgvPendings.RowCount = dgvPendings.RowCount + 1
                End If

                y = y + 1
            Loop
        End If

End Function


Private Sub dgvPendings_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvPendings.CellDoubleClick
    refreshPendingsGrid()
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code that re-populates the grid?

Comment: Why are you calling `refreshPendingsGrid` subroutine on every double-click in cell?

Comment: I added the code for re-population. Basically, it checks if there are any data in the dataset and populates the datagridview.

Comment: @MaciejLos there is more going on, I simplified the code just to focus on the issue.

Comment: The answer to the question: "why?" is very important, because i found no reason to redraw or repopulate entire datagridview. You have to re-load only currently edited record.

Comment: @MaciejLos the purpose of refreshing the datagrid is to remove records that were "resolved". Information in the datagrid is populated based in SQL query, and it is possible that resolving one record would remove more than one from the datagrid. That's why I want to refresh it every time

Comment: Thank you everyone for the feedback. The problem is resolved by commenting out Application.DoEvents().

Comment: If you ever think that using `Application.DoEvents` is a good idea, there's a 99.9% chance you're trying to solve a problem of your own creation and you should rethink your original code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved by commenting out Application.DoEvents()